Volumetric shaders in blender: unexpected 'hollow' appearance
I am having some issues understanding how Blender is rendering volumetric shaders in certain cases, where objects appear to be hollow when they shouldn't. When I say hollow, the density of the volumetrics changes along the line where the faces merge. In my opinion, it looks like something is wrong, but maybe I have a misunderstanding about how volumetrics should work.
My case using cycles in blender 4.2.1: I created two planes intersecting each other in different ways:


I created a plane, added a solidify modifier, duplicated the plane, and rotated it 90 degrees. After that, I joined the two planes with a boolean modifier. Then I recalculated the normals to face outwards. (see image with volumetric shader)

I created a plane, extruded it along z, then added loop cuts, and extruded one face upwards and the other downwards to get something similar to the case above. After the process, I recalculated the normals to face outwards and applied the volumetric shader.

Same as case 2, but I added a remesh modifier with a very small voxel size. I applied the boolean modifier.

Same as in case 1, I used two planes with a boolean modifier to join them. But I also duplicated the planes and added a second modifier that only keeps the intersection. So basically, I have a very tiny mesh in the center of the object that is only the intersection of the two planes. This is the only case where the object looks as expected and not hollow.


So my question is, why do objects seem to be hollow? Is this how they are supposed to look? As far as I understand, volumetrics should fill the whole volume inside the faces. If the normals of the faces are correct, everything should look like case 4. But I only manage to make it look like this by adding an extra volume.
How can I make everything look like case 4 without manually adding extra volume?
I already tried to increase the light paths, decreasing the volume step rate and still the same problem.
Thank you very much.


Apparently this is the expected behavior, quoting an answer that I've got from another place:

Everywhere else in the object you’re looking through two consecutive volumes, but at this particular point (line, really) if you trace a ray it’ll immediately exit the volume on the opposite corner

